# How do you include standard C++ libraries in Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino

For a project, I need to include some standard C++ libraries such as `vector`. That library also includes many other standard C++ libraries and so on.

I already have all of the standard C++ libraries in a folder. How can I include them into my Arduino code without changing the code of the library.

Comment: [Don't cross post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068) You already posted [this question on Arduino SE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/46998).

Comment: @gre_gor : I deleted the Question on Arduino SE. I waited like 8h for an answer and didn't get any. I believe that this question can also benefit Stack Overflow so I posted it here.

Comment: The question was [a dupe](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/24790) there. And the answer here is stolen from that dupe.

Comment: @gre_gor I don't think that stealing is correct word in this context. I've just googled and tried to search solution, I found it and posted it here, its that simple.

Comment: @T.Gomareli Most of your answer is just copy pasted with only slight changes without any attribution. Read: [Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077).

Comment: @gre_gor I will do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since there hasn't been any replies yet, and while I'm no authority on this... I think normally, you plain can't include standard C++ libraries in Arduino.

Those standard libraries work for whatever system you're running and I assume they were not meant for an Arduino. For instance, how does an Arduino do cout or cin? Arduino uses the Atmel chipset and whatever C++ libraries Atmel implemented, is what you're gonna get.

But if you need C++ vectors, there are Arduino solutions that I Googled: 
https://github.com/tomstewart89/Vector

Hopefully you can find if others have already built the functionality that you require, there's some useful open source projects available depending on what you want to do.